# Return table row td item from div class without using onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple table like below:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>img</td>
           <td class="mediaTitle"><span class="media_title">Media Name Title</span></td>
           <td>type</td>
           <td>2017-08-30 10:30am</td>
           <td>2017-09-01 11:34am</td>
           <td>Smith, Tater</td>
           <td><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down action" data-action="download_media" title="Download Media" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
           <td><i class="fa fa-refresh action" data-action="restore_media" title="Restore Media" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
           <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o action" data-action="delete_media" title="Permanently Delete Media" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The theory with this table is it will output hundreds of rows via dynamic data. I have written a javascript method to a `data-action` called `delete_media`, where I am trying to get the title of the current row's text value inside the `td tr.mediaTitle` by clicking on a link with the div class `.fa-trash-o`. Seems simple enough.

I am using this function as of now, where I use `$(this)` thinking that `$(this)` refers to the button being clicked, and from there I traverse up the DOM tree:

```
Blah.prototype._delete_media = function(data,e,el) {
        var self = this,
            mediaTitle = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.mediaTitle').text();

        console.log(mediaTitle);
});
```

This is returned undefined or a blank value. Not what I am looking for.

But when I wrap it in a `.onClick` then I am able to get the `.text()` value as desired:

```
Blah.prototype._delete_media = function(data,e,el) {
        var self = this;

        $('.fa-trash-o').click(function() {
            var mediaTitle = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.mediaTitle').text();

        console.log(mediaTitle);
        });
});
```

Ok. Confusing.

Now, obviously it doesn't make sense to use a `.onClick` function inside a method that is already tied to a `data-action`. From what I can tell, I am not using the `$(this)` correctly in my first/desired method. I am missing something here, and looking to someone smarter than me to help me find the missing piece in my jQuery learning. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are selecting ALL elements and adding a click. Is that what you really want? How is `_delete_media` called.... we need to see more code.

Comment: `this` inside a click event handler has nothing to do with what `this` is outside of it

Comment: `_delete_media` is called via an `action` event method

Comment: @HollerTrain that's not enough detail to know what `this` is. It is probably the new `Blah` instance

Comment: @HollerTrain Your objective is to get the text of that particular `<td>` with a button that's on the same row? Use `$(e.target)` for the button instead of `$(this)`

Comment: Can you show the code where you called `_delete_media` & what is `el`?
`$(el).closest('tr')` will work if it is the clicked element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

Change `$(this)` to `$(e.target)`. In the demo I added another row then numbered the text to tell them apart.

---

You don't have to traverse the DOM so much, the selector `td.mediaTitle` can be used directly.

### Demo

```js
$('.fa-trash-o').on('click', function(e) {
  var mediaTitle = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('td.mediaTitle').text();

  console.log(mediaTitle);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>img</td>
      <td class="mediaTitle">
        <span class="media_title">Media Name Title 1
             </span>
      </td>
      <td>type</td>
      <td>2017-08-30 10:30am</td>
      <td>2017-09-01 11:34am</td>
      <td>Smith, Tater</td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>img</td>
      <td class="mediaTitle">
        <span class="media_title">Media Name Title 2
             </span>
      </td>
      <td>type</td>
      <td>2017-08-30 10:30am</td>
      <td>2017-09-01 11:34am</td>
      <td>Smith, Tater</td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add another row and see it's not that simple

Comment: the point of this post is i can use `.onClick` fine, but that defeats the purpose of using an event handler. i'm trying to use the first method i posted and not rely on a `onClick` step

Comment: very cool. i tried this out and you are correct. using `$(e.target)` was the correct way, allowing me to target the clicked row without forcing myself to use a `onClick` method. you rock!

Comment: You're welcome, `$(this)` normally works as well, but it looks like the `prototype.Object` is `$(this)` probably. If your method wasn't event driven (i.e. button), then you probably need to use `.bind()` in order to change the `this`. Luckily you didn't need to go that route because `e.target` is a strong and accurate property that is old as dirt so it's very stable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you could take wrapping this all into a simple plugin. The only click event is delegated to the table itself to account for future rows being dynamically added.

Each `[data-action]` has it's own `actionMethod`. 
Each row uses data attributes related to each media item

Usage : `$('#my-table').mediaActions()`

Since you aren't likely to have numerous instances simultaneously I don't see any big advantage to using proptotype inheritance. All the named functions will be isolated inside the IIFE wrapping the plugn

```js
(function($) {
  // hoisted references to functions at bottom
  var actionMethods = {
    'restore_media' : restore_media,
    'delete_media'  : delete_media,
    'download_media': download_media
  };

  $.fn.mediaActions = function(opts) {
    // return this to allow jQuery chaining
    return this.each(function() {
      // delegate clcik listener to the table with `[data-action]` targets
      $(this).on('click', '[data-action]', function(e) {
        var $el = $(this),
          $row = $el.closest('tr'),
          action = $el.data('action'),
          media_data = $row.data();
        // call method for this action passing in current row and row data
        // TODO : make sure method exists for current action
        actionMethods[action]($row, media_data);
      });
    })
  }

  function restore_media($row, media_data) {
    // somehow validate it needs restoring first
    console.log('Restoring', media_data);
    $row.removeClass('deleted');
  }

  function delete_media($row, media_data) {
    console.log('Deleting', media_data);
    $row.addClass('deleted');
  }

  function download_media($row, media_data) {
    console.log('Downloading', media_data);
  }

})(jQuery);
$('#my-table').mediaActions()
```

```css
tr.deleted {
  background: #ccc
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table id="my-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-media_title="Media Name Title" data-media_id="1234">
      <td>img</td>
      <td class="mediaTitle"><span class="media_title">Media Name Title</span></td>
      <td>type</td>
      <td>2017-08-30 10:30am</td>
      <td>2017-09-01 11:34am</td>
      <td>Smith, Tater</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down action" data-action="download_media" title="Download Media" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-refresh action" data-action="restore_media" title="Restore Media" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o action" data-action="delete_media" title="Permanently Delete Media" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-media_title="Media  2" data-media_id="678">
      <td>img</td>
      <td class="mediaTitle"><span class="media_title">Media  2</span></td>
      <td>type</td>
      <td>2017-08-30 10:30am</td>
      <td>2017-09-01 11:34am</td>
      <td>Foo, Bar</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down action" data-action="download_media" title="Download Media" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-refresh action" data-action="restore_media" title="Restore Media" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o action" data-action="delete_media" title="Permanently Delete Media" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```